Error monitoring Synology active agent snmp zabbix
I am trying to monitor a synology DS218j using zabbix 6.4.
The infrastructure of the client that has this device installed has no hyper-v or any other kind of hypervisor for installing any zabbix proxy, so the only way to monitor that is making it using active monitoring via SNMP.
On the side of the Synology I have the following configuration:
enter image description here
The SNMP is enabled and the community is public.
On the side of the Zabbix Server where I want to add the synology in order to monitor it I have the following configuration:
enter image description here
The hostname is the same that appears on the control panel of the synology,
The templates are the following ones: Template SNMP Disks and Template Synology DiskStation
The ip address is the same that the Synology has, and I have added it using the SNMP interface
The {$SNMP_COMMUNITY} is public, the same that I configured on the synology
and the {$SNMP_PORT} is 161 (the SNMP port)
But I get no signal:
enter image description here
What might be the problem? Is there something missing?
